# How to edit the properties of application theme programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, I am allowing user to pick up the background color, font size. Once these are selected, this new background color will be applicable to each view in activity and application.

So how to change this background color to apply it on all the views in the activity?

I would like to achieve this as application theme property. That means the changed color should be reflected on views of each activity of my app whenever they are launched.

Is there a simple way to do this?
Otherwise, I will have to set the background color property for each view individually.

All the related posts to this question discuss about changing between the pre-existing themes.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the background color the user selected, you could save that in a sharedpreference. Then, in each activity's onCreate, you could receive the sharedpreference value and set the background color.

setting the background color is simple:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

to work with sharedpreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("color", MODE_PRIVATE);

String color = sp.getString("colorChoice", "BLACK");
```

The code above declares a variable of type sharedpreferences: "color" is like the group. Then, you declare a String variable which calls sp.getString(): "BLACK" is the default value.

and to save to sharedpreferences:

```
Editor edit = sp.edit();
edit.putString("colorChoice", "Whatever the user selects here");
edit.commit();
```

The above code could be used when the user selects what color they want the background to be.

Now, if you want it to work for ALL the views in the activity just create a method that either has view as its argument (then you need to call this method for each view), or use a viewgroup and call its children. something like this:

```
    private void unbindDrawables(View view){
    if (view.getBackground() != null){
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup){
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++){
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));

        }//for loop
        try {
            ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Note this method does not set background color. This is just an example of using viewgroup and calling each view recursively. The method above is used to clear views, specifically, of bitmaps.

Comment: Currently, I am doing the same i.e. setting the values in SharedPreferences, retrieving them in onCreate and setting them. But as I mentioned earlier, this has to be done for all the views which becomes repititive. So, I just want a method to reduce that work.